# ArgumentException when Delegate.CreateDelegate is called with a function signature that contains an interface.

Tags: c#, soap, delegates, .net-core, wsdl

**Context**

Currently I am creating an Extract Load and Transform (ETL) application written in C# with .NET Core. The source of the ETL application is a Soap webservice, which contains a multitude of methods. Each entity (Employee, Company, etc) and way of retrieving (ByKey, ByQuery, etc) has its own Soap webservice method. For example if I were to retrieve the entity 'Employee' by executing a query, I would call the `GetEmployeeByQuery` method. All methods return a string with XML.

Visual Studio generated proxy classes of this webservice by its WSDL file (generated indirectly through dotnet-svcutil). Unfortunately the proxy classes generated for this service seem to be generated according to a message contract pattern. This means that the proxy method `GetEmployeeByQuery` returns the `GetEmployeeByQueryResponse` partial class, which has a field `Body` that contains the `GetEmployeesByQueryResponseBody` partial class. The actual result is located in a string field on the `GetEmployeeByQueryResponseBody` that has the name of `GetEmployeeByQueryResult`.

Attempts to adjust the code generation, to produce proxy classes that do not adhere to the message contract pattern have not been fruitful. Adjusting the the option `GenerateMessageContract` in the 'ConnectedService.json' file or using the dotnet-svcutil.exe tool directly have not led to any changes in the generated code.

*Note: In the .NET Framework the generated code does not adhere to the message contract pattern.*

**The Goal**

Ideally the ETL application is able to invoke Soap webservice methods through reflection and on the basis of its configuration. The configuration contains the method and parameters to call, and through some factories this results in a Delegate (or something similar like MethodInfo object) that can be called elsewhere in the application. This delegate should be generic and not tied to any specific entity.

Dynamically invoking the generated Soap webservice methods, is made considerably more complicated by the message contract (partial) classes '...Response' and '...ResponseBody'. Rather than having a mostly similar method signature for each generated proxy method (parameters and return type are always string). I now have a different method signature for each generated proxy method and thus for each entity.

The reason I hope to have the same delegate for multiple methods is because the the actions executed per entity type are effectively the same. Rather than writing code for each individual entity, I'd like to to this in a entity independent way.

**The Problem**

My current solution is to create a entity independent delegate. To ensure that the delegate has the same method signature, an interface is placed on the generated classes. The generated `...Response` and `...ResponseBody` classes are partial. I extend these classes in another file and implement an interface on them. This interface allows me to retrieve the results irrespective of which entity type it is.

*Interface*

```
public interface IMessageResult<T>
{
    T GetResult();
}
```

*Interface Implementation*

```
public partial class GetUDICByQueryResponse : IMessageResult<string>
{
    public string GetResult()
    {
        return Body.GetUDICByQueryResult;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to create a delegate successfully. Whenever I try to create a delegate through Delegate.CreateDelegate I get the following error:

```
Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

This does not happen when I use the concrete class, instead of the interface.

*Helper for creating delegates*

```
public static TMethodSignature GetLocalMethod<TMethodSignature>(object classInstance, string methodName)
        where TMethodSignature : class
    {
        Type methodSignature = typeof(TMethodSignature);

        TMethodSignature method = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            methodSignature,
            classInstance,
            methodName) as TMethodSignature;

        if (method == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Method {methodName} could not be cast into a delegate. The given method signature could not be found.");

        return method;
    }
```

*Calling helper method*

```
var soapMethod = ReflectionUtils.GetLocalMethod<Func<string, string, string, string, Task<IMessageResult<string>>>>(Service, parameters.MethodName);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some leisure time, I was able to see why this isn't working (a silly mistake). The Soap webservice method I am trying to retrieve has a signature that is only defined with the specific (response) class Type. There is no method that is defined where the response is defined with the interface. Therefore the Delegate.CreateDelegate() method is not able to bind the target method.

The larger problem I am facing, how to call the Soap webservice methods via reflection through the application configuration, still stands however.